# Flex-AIR: Make application with NO tab in taskbar?

Tags: apache-flex, air

I have an AIR app about half way done right now. I was informed by the client today that he does not want a tab to show up in his task bar. I already have this in place for new windows by making them lightweight. I do not know how to make the main window lightweight though. If there is not a way, is there a work around, like not not having a main window and just opening lightweight windows, don't know how that could be done either though? Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [this doc out.](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=taskbar_1.html) -- Yes, you can do this. In short, you have to hide the initial window - then display your application in a lightweight window.

Also - do note: On a Mac - the behavior is different. By convention, a window is not shown in the 'task bar' when it is displayed. When it is minimized it is in the bar. To hide the application when minimized on a Mac - you have to make the window 'invisible' instead of minimizing it. The doc mentioned above gives further details.

The key part of the doc for your case:

> On the Windows operating system,
> windows created with the types utility
> or lightweight do not appear on the
> taskbar. Invisible windows do not
> appear on the taskbar, either.
>
> **Because the initial window is
> necessarily of type, normal, in order
> to create an application without any
> windows appearing in the taskbar, you
> must either close the inital window or
> leave it invisible.**
>
> To close all
> windows in your application without
> terminating the application, set the
> autoExit property of the
> NativeApplication object to false
> before closing the last window. To
> simply prevent the intial window from
> ever becoming visible, add
> false to the
>  element of the
> application descriptor file (and do
> not set the visible property to true
> or call the activate() method of the
> window).
>
> **In new windows opened by the
> application, set the type property of
> the NativeWindowInitOption object
> passed to the window constructor to
> NativeWindowType.UTILITY or
> NativeWindowType.LIGHTWEIGHT.**