# Flex/Adobe Air application as service

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, air, flexbuilder, embedded-linux

Is it possible to develop flex/Air application  as a service.
The application doesn't require any GUI it should run as service in embedded Linux/Linux/Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AIR cannot run as a true service. But it can be started on user login (not with system start) with `NativeApplication.nativeApplication.startAtLogin = true` and you can hide it from taskbar (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100480/flex-air-make-application-with-no-tab-in-taskbar)), so you can get quite close to service behavior.